# Unable to push the commits to Google Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: git, google-source-repositories

I am unable to push the commits to the remote When I try to push I am getting an error.

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 356 bytes | 356.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
send-pack: protocol error: bad band #69
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '{Git remote url}'
```

I have created an issue in issuetracker [Public Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/149241388)

Please help me to resove thins

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. It's Because of the google cloud project was not associated with an active billing account. Once the project was associated with the **active** billing account. I was able to push the code again.